# Retrieve Data from website and display in android App

Tags: wordpress

I am fresher for developing Android App. i have queries.

1. How can I retrieve website specific content and display it in android App? I don't know where to start.
2. In login page Activity which contains `username`, `password` and `Login` button Here only registered user from website can login to it.How to do validation only for already registered user from website?

Comment: i am not familiar with android application, but know that if you want to fetch the data from a website and display it into the android app then you need the data into `JSON` or `XML` format.

Answer (score 0):

[XML-RPC WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) is the best place to start.

If you go through the API, you can easily figure out that you have all operations available for you, and all you need to do is, use a xmlrpc client library for java to call those procedures. And, [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/) library looks decent.